# How to remove elixir package on hex

Tags: elixir, hex-pm

I want to remove published elixir package on hex. I already know that I can only delete it up to one hour after creation with this command.

```
mix hex.publish --revert VERSION
```

But, Is there another way to delete package that is over one hour after creation on hex ? Thanks for every suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting the [documentation](https://hex.pm/docs/tasks#hex_publish) of the `hex.publish` mix task:

> If you want to revert a publication that is more than one hour old you need to contact an administrator.

Comment: Is there a standard way to contract an administrator. I published a version by mistake from a feature branch, as the package (ace) currently has zero downloads it seams a shame I can't fix my mistake.

Comment: And if the package was publish less than an hour ago?

Answer (score 3):

You can revert to a package back to the starting point with no version.

```
mix hex.publish --revert 0.0.1
```

This will revert the version 0.0.1 published and will leave the package with no code in it, just the name for now until admin will remove the package as requested.